# How to remove a block itself near another specific block

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to know how to do this in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. For example: A player placed a chest near piston, is there any way to remove the chest itself near the piston?

Comment: In MCJava you would do raytracing to get the position of the chest and then check blocks nearby with `/execute if block` or whatever and then simply use `/setblock` or `/fill` to remove the chest. I have no idea which parts of that would work in MCBE, which would be different and which just impossible, but maybe you can do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 air 0 replace chest
```

Replace the x1-z2 arguments with actual coordinates that describe the diagonal of the volume you're checking.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to do this is with either commands, or a headless piston. You can use TNT too, but that would destroy the piston, and you probably don’t want that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We appreciate your answer, but could you explain what a headless piston is?

Comment: perhaps a piston without the wooden part? *wait, that's illegal*